# oclint-json-compilation-database loops indefinitely

Tags: ios, xcode, oclint

I'm integrating OCLint tool in an Xcode project to do some static analysis but I'm getting what seems to be a bug in the OCLint tool. I'm using `OCLint 0.8.1` and this is what I do:

1. Build my project

`$ xcodebuild 
-workspace "Reduced.xcworkspace" 
-scheme "Reduced" \
clean build > xcodebuild.log`

**(correctly generates xcodebuild.log of 24.6 MB)**

2. Generate `compile_commands.json`

`$ oclint-xcodebuild`

**(correctly generates compile_commands.json of 18.7 MB)**

3. Analyse `compile_commands.json`

`$ oclint-json-compilation-database`

This last command starts sending output non-stop with a pattern:

27 errors generated.
1 error generated.
1 error generated.
2 errors generated.
2 errors generated.
2 errors generated.
4 errors generated.
2 errors generated.
11 errors generated.
2 errors generated.
2 errors generated.
4 errors generated.
2 errors generated.
1 error generated.
2 errors generated.
5 errors generated.

27 errors generated.
1 error generated.
1 error generated.
2 errors generated.
2 errors generated.
2 errors generated.
4 errors generated.
2 errors generated.
11 errors generated.
2 errors generated.
2 errors generated.
4 errors generated.
2 errors generated.
1 error generated.
2 errors generated.
5 errors generated.

27 errors generated.
1 error generated.
1 error generated.
2 errors generated.
2 errors generated.
2 errors generated.
4 errors generated.
2 errors generated.
11 errors generated.
2 errors generated.
2 errors generated.
4 errors generated.
2 errors generated.
1 error generated.
2 errors generated.
5 errors generated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to latest OCLint (0.10.2) fixed this for me.

```
brew upgrade oclint
```